# Using webbrowser module to use Google Maps

Tags: python, module, sys, pyperclip

i'm just new to python and i want to ask a simple question.
what's the difference between using this code:

```
    import webbrowser, pyperclip, sys        

    chrome = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"

    def location_finder():
        output = input('Type the place you want to find!\n')

        webbrowser.get(chrome).open('https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + output)

    location_finder()
```

and this code:

```
    import webbrowser, pyperclip, sys  

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
    else:
        address = pyperclip.paste()  

    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address)
```

Comment: Everything. Or are the docs broken?

Answer (score 0):

The diffrent is:

1. With the first one, using target browser is `chrome.exe` and the second is using the default browser.
2. The first code using import from built in function `input` and the second code `sys.argv`is automatically a list of strings representing the arguments (as separated by spaces) on the command-line. The `sys.argv[1:]` get everything after the script name.